Access specifiers ignored in unevaluated context
Is MSVC wrong for accepting this code and ignoring the private member access of s::a? If so, why?
class s { int x; };
static_assert(sizeof(s::x)); // clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok

Demo

Clang's error message:
<source>:2:25: error: 'x' is a private member of 's'
    2 | static_assert(sizeof(s::x));
      |                         ^
<source>:1:15: note: implicitly declared private here
    1 | class s { int x; };
      |               ^

GCC's error message:
<source>:2:25: error: 'int s::x' is private within this context
    2 | static_assert(sizeof(s::x));
      |                         ^
<source>:1:15: note: declared private here
    1 | class s { int x; };
      |               ^


As far as I can tell, the standard doesn't distinguish between evaluated and non-evaluated context here.
Quote from [class.access]#4:

Access control is applied uniformly to all names, whether the names are referred to from declarations or
expressions. [Note: Access control applies to names nominated by friend declarations (11.9.3) and using-
declarations (9.9). — end note] In the case of overloaded function names, access control is applied to the
function selected by overload resolution.

sizeof(s::x) is an expression, so access control should be taken into account - gcc and clang are correct.

"As far as I can tell, the standard doesn't distinguish between evaluated and non-evaluated context here." It has to, as s::x is an id-expression that denotes a non-static data-member, see also [expr.prim.id.general]/4.3.

@303 "here" being "in terms of access control"

that sounds correct
